# Using for/while loops and range() to list values

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, range

I am stuck with 2 ways of how to use for and while loops in listing values to empty lists.

**Example 1.**
Creating a function that takes in user's input and lists positive decimal values in a list UNTIL user inserts negative value. Then listing ends and the last value should be this negative value. How the output should look like:

Add a number to the list:
1.5
Add a number to the list:
5.2
Add a number to the list:
6
Add a number to the list:
-2
The list: [1.5, 5.2, 6.0, -2.0]

**My tryout that didn't work out**

```
list = []
positive = float(input("Add number to put it in list:"))

while positive > 0: 
    list.append(positive)
else:
    print(list)
```

**Example 2**
Another problem about using for loop and range() together: How to list first 20 even numbers starting from number 2. At the end of function print out the list with 20 values.

**My tryout that didn't work out**

```
emptylist = []
for days in range(40): 
    if days % 2 == 0: 
        print(emptylist)
```

Thanks already in advance to help me solve these applications! :)

Comment: This seems like a school assignment to me

Comment: You're only asking for `input` once, and then continue to loop on that input indefinitely. If you want to ask the user for more than one input, you need to have `input()` inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask for the user input inside the loop

```
numbers = []
num = 1
while num > 0:
    num = float(input("Add number to put it in list:"))
    numbers.append(num)
else:
    print(numbers)
```

As a side note, don't use `list` as a variable, it's a built-in name.

Answer (score 0):

You must replace your while with an if else

```
positive=1
list = []
while(positive):

    positive = float(input("Add number to put it in list:"))

    if positive > 0: 
        list.append(positive)
    else:
        print(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer for part-I:**

```
output_list = []
isPositive=True
while(isPositive):
    num = float(input())

    if (num > 0):
        output_list.append(num)
    else:
        isPositive=False
        output_list.append(num)
        break

print (output_list)
```

**Answer for part-II:**

```
>>> n=20
>>> for num in range(2,n*2+1,2):
...     print(num)
... 
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20
22
24
26
28
30
32
34
36
38
40
```